# Adding a Control per Mouse Click in Run Time

Tags: wpf, runtime, controls, mouse

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        Button button1 = new Button();
        Point tPosition = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
        button1.Margin = new Thickness(tPosition.X,tPosition.Y,0,0) ;
        button1.Width = 75;
        this.AddChild(button1);
    }
}
```

I think the code is pretty self-explanatory, I used a code that is approved in other thread here in stackoverflow, it doesn't give any error, but it also doesn't show up, do I need to refresh the window? And how?

by request, the XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Ampeldingensthingy.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid MouseLeftButtonDown="Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown" Name="hans">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="398*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="105*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I think you need to have a container like stackPanel or grid to add children into it.

Answer (score 0):

Window can have only one children and I think you already have one that is Grid whose MouseButtonDown you subscribing. Give a name to that Grid and then replace

this.AddChild(button1);

with

```
grid.Children.Add(button1);
```

here grid is the name given to Grid.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public StackPanel SPanel{get;set;}
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SPanel = new StackPanel { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical };
        }

        private void Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {              

            Button button1 = new Button();
            Point tPosition = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
            button1.Margin = new Thickness(tPosition.X,tPosition.Y,0,0) ;
            button1.Width = 75;
            SPanel.Children.Add(button1);
            window.Content = SPanel;
        }
    }
```

try to do the same with a canvas. the buttons will popup at the position you gave them.

Answer (score 0):

The object "this" depicts the Window object here. Content of a ContentControl must be a single element. Hence append the Button that is "button1" inside a parent Grid. For example

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button button1 = new Button();
            Point tPosition = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
            button1.Margin = new Thickness(tPosition.X, tPosition.Y, 0, 0);
            button1.Width = 75;
            MainGrid.Children.Add(button1);
        }
```

And in your Xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="click" Grid.Row="1"/>

    </Grid>
```